# Win-7 Upgrade from VISTA is refused with error: Upgrade from XP not supportet

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, upgrade

I did an successful upgrade from XP-Pro 32-bit to Vista Business SP1 32-bit. Now I want to do an upgrade to Win-7 Pro 32-bit. After checking the Vista Partition, the setup program fails with the error message: Upgrade from XP to Win-7 is not supportet ???

But the running OS is definitely an activated Vista Business installation !!!
So it seems that Win-7 setup refuses the upgrade, because it found some older XP files?

I couldn't find any hints for this mess on the web. So it would be fine, if anyone got the same problem and found a solution.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Contact Microsoft